# Authentication Challenge Method Is Not Called When Using NSURLSession Custom Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlsession

I'm working on an iOS app which connects to an ASP.NET Web API through Restful services. I want to use a custom delegate to handle authentication challenge. But the delegate method doesn't get called.

The http request is written in the following method within a view controller:

```
- (IBAction)test:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Get Bearer Token
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]      initWithIdentifier:@"BearerToken" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *bearerToken = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

    //Configure request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"......"]; //Replace the .... with real IP Address
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", bearerToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    //Configure session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    AuthChallengeDelegate *authChallengeDel = [[AuthChallengeDelegate alloc] init];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                          delegate:authChallengeDel
                                                     delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [task resume];
}
```

In the AuthChallengeDelegate class, I have implemented the following method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"%@", response);   
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,
                             NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"did receive challenge method called");
    NSLog(@"%@", challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod);
}
```

The first method (didReceiveResponse) get called and the response status code is 401 with "Www-Authenticate" = Bearer in the header field. But the second method (didReceiveChallenge) is not called. Anyone here could give me an idea of why it's not called?

(I'm using Xcode 6 and simulating in iOS8)

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to implement the session *task* delegate for the challenge/response, i.e. [URLSession(_:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:), as well as the session-level delegate. (The method of the delegate you're currently implementing handles session/server-level challenges; the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate version handles task-level challenges.)

Comment: Did you make this work? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hi Vannens, I didn't make it work. But I found my server side didn't issue challenge. Not sure about iOS side at the moment.

Comment: @Dean After moving to PROD I started to getting this issue. I have feeling that my problem is backend as well. So how did you fix it in the backend?

Comment: @Ramis, I didn't use the AuthChallengeDelegate in the end. My server returns 401 if user is not authenticated. So I just wrote a method in the app to handle 401.

Comment: please try https://stackoverflow.com/a/75705236/2553730

Answer (score 9):

There are two different challenge/response handlers in NSURLSession's delegates. The first, which you're implementing, is at the session level, and basically handles server-level authentication. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:):

> - For session-level challenges—NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM, NSURLAuthenticationMethodNegotiate, NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate, or NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust—the NSURLSession object calls the session delegate’s URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: method. If your app does not provide a session delegate method, the NSURLSession object calls the task delegate’s URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: method to handle the challenge.
> - For non-session-level challenges (all others), the NSURLSession object calls the session delegate’s URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: method to handle the challenge. If your app provides a session delegate and you need to handle authentication, then you must either handle the authentication at the task level or provide a task-level handler that calls the per-session handler explicitly. **The session delegate’s URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: method is not called for non-session-level challenges.**

So, you probably want to handle task-level authentication by adding protocol support for  NSURLSession**Task**Delegate in your delegate object, and supplying a handler at the task level, i.e.
`URLSession(_:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:)`.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the non-session-level method, and it is not called either.

Comment: As of iOS 8.1 I have same issue.  I've noticed that the call occurs in iOS 7.1.

Comment: I should add that my issue is with TLS authentication which doesn't require the fore mentioned header.

Comment: Yep, this method is not getting triggered on each request. I would expect it to be triggered with each new task, but nope.

Comment: how to handle proxy-authentiction?

Comment: THANK YOU!! I was trying to solve this thing for EVER <3

Answer (score 8):

From [iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html)

> Important: The URL loading system classes do not call their delegates to handle request challenges unless the server response contains a WWW-Authenticate header.

From where we understand that `didReceiveChallenge` methods should be called **BUT** the method `URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` gets called only when the header looks like `'WWW-Authenticate':'Basic'`

I haven't found any solution how to handle token based authentication where header is `'WWW-Authenticate':'Bearer'` as in question using Authentication Challenges.

Answer (score 3):

if You write:

```
AuthChallengeDelegate *authChallengeDel = [[AuthChallengeDelegate alloc] init];
```

authChallengeDel is LOCAL so will be released as soon as you exit methods.
So make it a property

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue is related to iOS 8 but if you are using iOS 9 please also keep in mind that the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key in your `Info.plist` is now mandatory for targeting any specific domain names.

I was having the exact same issue and used wireshark to look at the TLS network layer to check what version of TLS was used by the image server I was targeting.

Based on that you can add this to your `Info.plist` and that can hopefully solves this problem

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.0</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I thought that was overloading a method but was using a wrong signature.

Answer (score -1):

Try change delegate:authChallengeDel to delegate:self