# URLSession delegates not called after authentication challenge

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, nsurlsession

I'm making a post call to a server and I kept getting the error that the server certificate was invalid, so after researching I found that i must trust the server using authentication challenge. This goes through perfectly fine (I print the authentication challenge to make sure it does) but the rest of the call does not go through and i cannot get information back from my server, nothing happens after the authentication challenge, normally I'd expect to be returned data. However nothing happens and none of my urlsessiondatadelegates are called (checked with breaks).

Can anyone spot why it may be? Code:

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://45.56.105.97:7915/search-v2")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("Basic ***********", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

 let task = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
            task.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
               print(error)
                print(data)
                if let responseData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                                    print("data: \(responseData)")
                                    self.parseXML(data!)

                                }
        }.resume()
```

delegate methods:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print("did autherntcationchallenge = \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust  {
        print("send credential Server Trust")
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        challenge.sender!.use(credential, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic{
        print("send credential HTTP Basic")
        let defaultCredentials: URLCredential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence:URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        challenge.sender!.use(defaultCredentials, for: challenge)

    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM{
        print("send credential NTLM")

    } else{
        challenge.sender!.performDefaultHandling!(for: challenge)
    }

}
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("Data received: \(data)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

    print("Response received: \(response)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("something went wrong: \(error)")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
    print("rep: \(response)")
}
```

After running, all i get printed is:

did autherntcationchallenge = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
send credential Server Trust

I've also seen conversations about how I can only use either a closure or delegate methods for retrieving data/not both. I've tried everything with no success.

**Also I know I shouldnt just be blindly trusting the server, but I am trying to figure out why I cannot receive data back, I am aware this has serious security flaws.

Comment: When these delegate methods provide a completion handler, you have to call that completion handler, or else the connection will not proceed.

Comment: Is "urlsessiondatadelegates" called or not, if called then please share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- As Rob already mentioned in a comment, you aren't calling the completion handlers in any of your delegate methods.  This means that the connection will stop making progress at that point.
- You're calling methods on the challenge sender to provide credentials.  That would work with NSURLConnection, but NSURLSession requires you to do it by calling the completion handler.  Otherwise, things will break very badly, IIRC, e.g.

  ```
      completionHandler(.PerformDefaultHandling, nil)
  ```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it does indeed call the completion handler but I run into the error that: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be _________________. This was the same error that prompted me to include the authentication challenge delegate method.

Comment: That's because the server cert is invalid.  The way you solve that is to validate the certificate in some other way (e.g. by checking to see if its public key is the one you're expecting, or by modifying the protection space to allow a different root/anchor certificate and then checking the validity of the certificate again), and if it passes that validation, instead of performing default handling, you tell it to use the provided certificate.  Either way, you do it by calling the completion handler, because calling methods on the challenge sender won't do the right thing in any case.  :-)

Comment: I recommend reading this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html for additional background on how to write such a method.  It is all Obj-C, last I checked, but it at least gives you an idea of the various approaches you can use to do this safely.

Answer (score 1):

After spending almost one day for me it works after conforming to the protocol `URLSessionTaskDelegate` along with `URLSessionDelegate`.

```
class Snapshot: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
}
```

Hope it will help anyone facing the same issue.